# 'meteor build', cordova - error for ios platform

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I am trying to build my hello app (works on a web browser) for mobile platforms. I ran the command 'meteor build ../mobile/hello --server=localhost:3000' on the terminal. The build process for Android was successful but not for iOS.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

---

Error:

=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

While preparing Cordova project for platform iOS:
   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
   '/Users/John/apps/hello/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/hello.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'

---

I searched on google and some suggest it could be an issue with mobile-config.js file. I already checked that file and it seems ok.

```
// This section sets up some basic app metadata, the entire section is optional.
App.info({
  id: 'com.example.hello',
  name: 'hello',
  description: 'hello',
  author: 'John',
  email: 'contact@example.com',
  website: 'http://example.com'
});
// Set up resources such as icons and launch screens.
App.icons({
  'iphone': 'icons/phone.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'icons/phone2.png'
  // More screen sizes and platforms...
});
App.launchScreens({
  'iphone': 'splash/anotherPhone.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'splash/anotherPhone2.png'
  // More screen sizes and platforms...
});
// Set PhoneGap/Cordova preferences.
App.setPreference('BackgroundColor', '0xff0000ff');
App.setPreference('HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar', true);
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'default');
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'all', 'ios');
// Pass preferences for a particular PhoneGap/Cordova plugin.
App.configurePlugin('com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect', {
  APP_ID: '1234567890',
  API_KEY: 'supersecretapikey'
});
// Add custom tags for a particular PhoneGap/Cordova plugin to the end of the
// generated config.xml. 'Universal Links' is shown as an example here.
App.appendToConfig(`
  <universal-links>
    <host name="localhost:3000" />
  </universal-links>
`);
```

Comment: Have tried deleting your `<project-root>/.meteor/local` folder and running again?

Comment: Very nice! Thank you @ghybs. It ran smoothly after I deleted that directory.
What happened to the project before that deletion?

Comment: It happens sometimes that the `.meteor/local/cordova-build/` folder gets in a strange state. Deleting it and letting Meteor rebuild it solves the issue most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete from your project the folder /.meteor/local
2. launch Meteor again

Warning: you will loose your DataBase (it is located inside the local folder)

Tks @ghybs for the solution. I encountered the same issue and worked perfectly fine for me.